# Matlab FIR filter maximum absolute error

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

How can I determine the maximum absolute error (stopband and passband maximum ripple) for my filter?

```
% frequencies and amplitudes
f = [0.0 0.45 0.55 1.0];
a = [1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0];
% Parks-McCellan optimal FIR filter with N+1 (11) coefficients
[b, err, res] = firpm(10,f,a);
% impulse response
subplot(2,3,1);
stem(b);
title('Impulse response');

% frequency response of filter
[h,w] = freqz(b,256);
% magnitude of frequency response
subplot(2,3,2);
plot(abs(h));
title('Magnitude response')
% phase of frequency response
subplot(2,3,3);
plot(angle(h));
title('Phase response')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide picture of your plots? You should be able to estimate it from them.

Comment: Sure, but I need like 4 significant digits

Comment: I don't have a setup to confirm this, but the `err` return value should give you the maximum absolute error in cases where the bands have equal weights. With different weights you might have to multiply the error by the corresponding band's weight (or a normalized weight).

Comment: If I understand it correctly, `err` gives you `maximum ripple height` across all frequency points in `res.fgrid` - that's the maximum absolute error. As was already mentioned, you may have to consider `res.wt` for the frequency point associated with `err`. If you're interested in knowing ripples within the passband and the stopband(s) separately, `res.error` contains the `error at each point` in `res.fgrid`. `fgrid` should equate to the array of frequencies you provided at the input of `firpm()`.